# Повреждение внешнего жесткого диска

Tags: linux, linux-mint, hdd, iso

Сын создавая загрузочную флэшку через ultraiso вместо флэшки выбрал в программе внешний жесткий, программа выдала предупреждение, то диск используется и не может на него писать, после этого он увидел что выбрал не тот диск и прервал операцию. Но UltraIso все таки выполнило некоторые операции: метка диска изменилась. При подключении диска к компу с windows вместо привычных названий папок вижу набор символов. При подключении к линукс диск монтируется, но не открывается выдавая ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

df -h показывает, сколько места на диске свободно и занято и оно совпадает с тем что есть на самом деле. 
Т.е. информация на диске по идее должна сохраниться.
Как его восстановить чтобы он смог открываться как положено?

Comment: Zero Assumption Recovery может она поможет но она работает на Windows

Comment: такая же фигня была с флешкой вот ZAR и помог мне восстановить файлы

Comment: она восстанавливает файлы с диска на диск или она может восстановить этот диск чтобы он снова открывался как положено?

Comment: она восстанавливает файлы с диска на диск

Comment: Вот прочел в интернете и про  Hiren’s BootCD

Answer (score 2):

Не пытайтесь "починить диск", это невозможно (даже если оно смонтируется корректно, то наверняка будет содержать логические ошибки). Он сейчас подобен яйцу с разбитой скорлупой: вы можете только слить с него то, что осталось внутри, но каждое неосторожное движение может только навредить данным. И далеко не факт, что то, что будет слито - будет чем-то полезным.

Вообще, в профессиональном восстановлении данных, с диска обычно первым делом снимается посекторная копия (и точно не программами для домохозяек вроде творений Акрониса) и дальнейшие эксперименты идут уже с копией. Если с ней что-то случится - не жалко. В вашем случае это не слишком важно, так как физически диск не поврежден, но если охота обезопасить себя - нужен еще один такой диск для рабочей копии.

Потом берем любые интересные программы для восстановления данных. Этих программ великое множество, я бы посоветовал R-Studio, но это мое лично предпочтение, я ни в коем случае не могу сказать, что это что-то лучшее. И долго, осторожно, без лишней спешки, выковыриваем то, что осталось. На еще один диск. Потом все форматируем, с этого момента пути назад не будет и сливаем восстановленное обратно.

Comment: *В вашем случае это не слишком важно* Увы, важно. Современные ОС любят писАть на диск, даже если их никто не просит, достаточно подключить/смонтировать. *я бы посоветовал R-Studio* Я бы посоветовал все, до каких получится дотянуться. и во всех заложенных там режимах сканирования. Бывало не раз, что файл одна программа поднимает битым, а другая (а иногда та же, но в ином режиме) - нормально.

Comment: Согласен. Просто он уже пытался подключить его к работающей ОС, плохое уже случилось. Слишком хуже уже не будет.

Comment: @Akina, достаточно монтировать в readonly. современные операционные системы (к которым сложно отнести прямых потомков cp/m) это отлично умеют.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Большинство эвристиков-рековырялок из популярных - под Win, а там RO не сильно-то смонтируешь... Вернее, это можно, но сначала он опознается как RW, и только потом через DISKPART можно установить атрибут тома в RO. Впрочем, на файл журнала файловой системы этот RO вроде как не действует...

Comment: Более того, винда любит писать в МБР, еще до загрузки себя. Чем легко может поломать весь диск. На это принципе некоторые защиты от копирования работают - что-то изменилось на диске -> была попытка копирования диска.

Comment: @Akina, *а **там** RO не сильно-то смонтируешь* — ну я же не зря добавил оговорку про [«прямых потомков cp/m»](http://www.classiccmp.org/cpmarchives/site/images/cpm-inside4.png)

Comment: @bukkojot *винда любит писать в МБР, еще до загрузки себя* - вот с этого места - поподробнее... где это и что там в МБР пишется?

Comment: Сразу перед записями о разделах, сигнатура диска: https://habrahabr.ru/post/304014/